# Intermediate Code Generation

Tags: java, antlr, jasmin

I started using ANTLR 4 for my compiler course and I already created my grammar. ANTLR gives me the Lexer and the Parser but how can I generate an intermediate code? Someone told me to use Jasmin but I did't know how to use it.

NB: ANTLR gives me the java code.

Comment: What is "intermediate code"?

Comment: @Vampire  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation#Intermediate_language

Comment: So you mean how to generate the Java bytecode out of your custom language that you parsed with your ANTLR parser / lexer? If so, then you should write so. ;-)

Comment: @Tadesse: Your compiler class doesn't have theory and lecture on how to define and build intermediate code?  You must have an awful compiler class.  Get any textbook on compilers (Aho/Ullman/Sethi "Compiler") and *read* the chapters on this topic.    You still have work to do, but with the principles understood this is a matter of programming.

Comment: @Vampire:  or, if OP didn't mean "Java bytecode", to leave that out because it isn't relevant.   I think Vince's answer defines it in a way that is more in line with a classic compiler course.

Comment: Here is a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOfFbVTfT2vbJ9qiw_6fWwBAmJAYV4iUm It is german, but has english subtitles (disclaimer: I am the author)

Answer (score 1):

As you was told, Jasmin is one way to generate the bytecode.
If you don't know how to use it, I suggest you learn how to use it.
For example read the [User Guide](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/guide.html).